# If the replication factor is 3, does it mean I need 4 nodes in a datacenter?

Tags: cassandra

I set keyspace like the following.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE name_of_keyspace WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1' : 3, 'dc2' : 3};
```

If I want to follow the rule of this keyspace, do I need to have 3 or 4 nodes in `dc1`?

The reason why I'm confused is that there are two different types of nodes, one is coordinator node and the other is general node that can be chosen when a node fails.
Should I include this coordinator node as part of general node and create only 3 nodes in `dc1` or create 4 nodes to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinator node is chosen at query time. All nodes have the same capabilities.

When you run a cluster with rf 3 and run a query, for a partition:

- need only one node up if you read/write with consistency level 1.
- need two nodes if you read/write with quorum or two CL
- three nodes if you read/write with all or three CL

Note that the read/writes are issued to all nodes that holds/should write the data, but the driver will wait for the configured level.

Check this [page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html) for more information about consistency levels.

So, you can run a 3 nodes cluster with rf 3,and depending on what CL you read/write you can survive 0, 1, or 2 nodes being down.

Answer (score 2):

In Cassandra all nodes can act as coordinator. So for a request that requires a coordinator the node the client connected to will act as a coordinator.

A RF of 3 with 4 nodes is fine for a DC, but it is not needed unless you have a capacity you are trying to reach with the extra node. In one of my clusters we have 18 nodes for capacity with a RF of 3. That's generally how you scale Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks @muru that better?